# Display sum of other inputs into another element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

### Question

How can I have an element dynamically display the sum of various inputs?

### Background

I have several text boxes (with the same class). I have 4 inputs, each with a number. Input 1 is "1", 2 is "2", etc.

I want the fifth box to contain the sum of "1, 2, 3, 4".

### Issue

I am struggling with the javascript.

- Ideally the fourth box with id final would update as any of the previous boxes are edited.
- Can I do it using the classes? that is my intent as the amount of inputs can vary, it will not always be four.

---

### HTML

```
<input type='text' id='txtFirst' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='txtSecond' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='txtThird' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='final' />
```

Comment: please demonstrate what you have tried. You have javascript and jquery listed as tags, but you haven't included any code

Comment: What is the actual application for this? You are doing this very wrong, and it is not optimal to ask a question to fit your specific (wrong) approach, in this case by giving those inputs the same class. You can nest them in another element, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.copyText').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = 0;
    $('.copyText').each(function(){
        val  = val + (+$(this).val());
    })
    $('#final').val(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtFirst' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='txtSecond' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='txtThird' class='copyText' /><br/>
<input type='text' id='final' />
```

Try this which uses jQuery (demo using 2.1.0)

```
$('.copyText').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = 0;
    $('.copyText').each(function(){
        val  = val + (+$(this).val());
    })
    $('#final').val(val);
})
```

To see the the working demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/517/). Or run the code snippet here.

Comment: This does not add properly calculate the inputs.

Comment: just updated code for input to be numbers. if you want test to be appeded to create result just remove + sign from (+$(this).val()).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery get the fields values :

```
$('.copyText').map(function(){return $(this).val();})
```

Transform to string with :

```
.get().join(',')
```

And assign it to #final with :

```
$("#final").val();
```

Conclusion :

```
$("#final").val($('.copyText').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(','));
```

Comment: Can you help us understand why you did it this way, thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Is there any chance you could show me an example in jfiddle?

Comment: @user2069576 YOU are supposed to take this and plug it into your example to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onload = _ => {
    //get the html elements
    const texts = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("copyText"));
    const out = document.getElementById("final");

    //a function for getting all the text values and updating the ouput
    function update(){
        out.value = texts.map( text => text.value ).join(", ");
    }

    //await input, then update
    texts.forEach( text => text.addEventListener("input", update) );
};
```